# ExtJS call funtion of another component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created a Ext.Mixin component and would like to call a function of it from another component. How do I have to do that? Must be very obvious, but I can't see right now.

EDIT:

```
Ext.define('ABC.mixin.MyMixin', {
    extend: 'Ext.Mixin',

    mixinConfig: {
        after: {
        },
        before: {
            initComponent: 'init'
        }
    },

    init: function () {
        let me = this;
        myfunction();
    },

    myfunction: function () {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

How do I call ***myfunction()*** ?

Comment: Post what your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I updated the question. Any advise now?

Answer (score 1):

When you include a mixin to a component all of the functions the mixin provides are included to the component itself.
So when you have a reference to your created component you cann call the function on the component itself.

```
Ext.define('ABC.mixin.MyMixin', {
    extend: 'Ext.Mixin',
    myfunction: function () {
        //do stuff
    }
});

Ext.define('ABC.view.MyView', {
    mixins: ['ABC.mixin.MyMixin'],
   // ...other config stuff
});

let myView = Ext.create('ABC.view.MyView');  // concreate Object of the class ABC.view.MyView
myView.myfunction();  // we can call the function of the mixin on the Object directly.
```

For more information see the [ExtJs documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-mixins)

Answer (score 0):

The [API Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-mixins) seem to provide the information you need. You just include your mixin in the component you need, like so:

```
Ext.define('ABC.view.MyComponent', {
       mixins: ['ABC.mixin.MyMixin'],

       initComponent() {
           this.myfunction();
           this.callParent();
       }
   });
```

And from the component's scope, call the mixin's functions you need